# How to suicide existing contract?

Tags: selfdestruct

Is there any way to suicide contract which was never designed for that?

If so what will happen with ethers that this contract is holding?

Answer (score 6):

No, if there is no code in the contract to `suicide` it then there is no way to destroy it. This is deliberate: People or other contracts have to know in advance whether it will still be there in the future, so it shouldn't be possible for someone to destroy it unless it included code that allows it to be destroyed.

If there is no code in the contract allowing anyone to withdraw its funds, they will be stuck there forever, unless Ethereum is changed to let someone move them.